# Primary Reason for Depreciating Lifecycle Hooks in React 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I'm trying to understand the primary reason(s) for depreciating the `componentWillMount`/`componentWillUpdate`/`componentWillReceiveProps` in `react` version 16.

At a high level, it seems like they are being depreciated because their naming encourages developers to make API calls that return after the next lifecycle events (e.g. `render`) have already occurred, and so the developer should be using the `componentDidX` counterpart.

So essentially, because of this, these lifecycle events are being depreciated and the `componentWillRecieveProps` is being put into a more aptly named `getDerivedStateFromProps` and the other `componentDidX` methods are being pushed.

Is this the general correct high level reasoning?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked of the react creators.

Answer (score 2):

Because React is implementing async rendering, this will cause lifecycle events like componentWillMount to be called more than once in some cases, that's why the React team is deprecating those methods and marking them as UNSAFE.

You can have some more details [in this link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

Update: The following post has good explanation on how the componentWillMount can be miss-used and hence they are marked by React core team as unsafe: [Revisiting use of React’s Component Life Cycle Hooks in Anticipation of Async Rendering](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-safely-use-reacts-life-cycles-with-fiber-s-async-rendering-fd4469ebbd8f)

Comment: *this will cause lifecycle events like componentWillMount to be called more than once in some cases* - can you provide an explanation for that? componentWillMount isn't supposed to be called more than once for component instance.

Comment: It is not yet 100% clear, as the anticipation is that once React moved to Fiber's asynchronous rendering, this lifecycle method will be problematic. That's why the React core team is advising developers agains using them. Also checkout [this post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-safely-use-reacts-life-cycles-with-fiber-s-async-rendering-fd4469ebbd8f)

Comment: This basically means that multiple instances may be created but only one of them will be mounted, this is not specific to componentWillMount. I'd say a cleaner explanation is that they were deprecated because these lifecycle hooks were previously commonly misused and this sort of misuse will cause even more problems with async rendering. That's a good link, I'd suggest to add it to the answer.

Comment: @Bilal can you explain this sentence `Allowing the main thread to handle something that needs to be displayed urgently like animation. This can involve throwing away already completed work`? Why would this involve throwing away work just because it's done in an async worker off of the main thread?